# How select and remove rows based on position for a specific range in R

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

Suppose I have two data frames like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,4,0,0),
             b = c(0,3,5,5,0),
             c = c(0,0,6,7,6))

df2 <- data.frame(a = c(3,6,8,0,0),
             b = c(0,9,10,4,0),
             c = c(0,0,1,4,9))
```

And then I joint it, like

```
df3 <- full_join(df1, df2)
print(df3)

   a  b c
1  1  0 0
2  2  3 0
3  4  5 6
4  0  5 7
5  0  0 6
6  3  0 0
7  6  9 0
8  8 10 1
9  0  4 4
10 0  0 9
```

Note that I have always the same pattern, with zeros in rows 1 and 2; and in rows 9 and 10. And I also have zeros between rows 4 and 7.
I want to remove, only, the zeros between rows 4 and 7.
So, I can solve it, like:

```
df3[4,1] <- NA
df3[5,1] <- NA
df3[5,2] <- NA
df3[6,2] <- NA
df3[6,3] <- NA
df3[7,3] <- NA

new.df3 <-  as.data.frame(lapply(df3, na.omit))
print(new.df3)

  a  b c
1 1  0 0
2 2  3 0
3 4  5 6
4 3  5 7
5 6  9 6
6 8 10 1
7 0  4 4
8 0  0 9
```

But it is not elegant and very time-consuming.
Any thoughts? I really appreciate it, thanks in advance.
Best!

Comment: "I want to remove, only, the zeros between rows 4 and 7." Is this meant to be a general rule, like "always remove repeated zeroes from the middle rows of the data frame, and shift later non-zeroes to occur earlier"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df3 %>%
  mutate(rn = between(row_number(), 4, 7)) %>%
  summarise(across(-rn, ~.x[!(.x == 0 & rn)]))
  a  b c
1 1  0 0
2 2  3 0
3 4  5 6
4 3  5 7
5 6  9 6
6 8 10 1
7 0  4 4
8 0  0 9
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you find which one is zero between rows 4 and 7.

```
to_remove <- apply(df3[4:7, ], 1, function(x) which(x == 0))
```

Then, you substitute them by NAs.

```
for(i in seq(length(to_remove))){
  df3[as.numeric(names(to_remove))[i], to_remove[[i]]] <- NA
}
```

And, finally, drop them.

```
new.df3 <-  as.data.frame(lapply(df3, na.omit))
print(new.df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach:

```
mask <- !(seq(nrow(df3)) %in% 4:7 & df3 == 0)
df.lst <- lapply(1:3, function(x) df3[mask[, x], x])
sapply(df.lst, length)
# [1] 8 8 8  # Check to make sure the columns are the same length
names(df.lst) <- colnames(df3)
(new.df3 <- as.data.frame(df.lst))
#   a  b c
# 1 1  0 0
# 2 2  3 0
# 3 4  5 6
# 4 3  5 7
# 5 6  9 6
# 6 8 10 1
# 7 0  4 4
# 8 0  0 9
```